# Where I can find exact code that Java compiler generates for the Enum.values() method?

Tags: java, enums

According to the Java specification `Enum.values()` method is generated by the compiler. However, I wasn't able to find exact code that those method uses. I can only look into the byte code:

```
public static values()[Lxx/enums/WidgetProperty;
   L0
    LINENUMBER 8 L0
    GETSTATIC xx/enums/WidgetProperty.$VALUES : [Lxx/enums/WidgetProperty;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL [Lxx/enums/WidgetProperty;.clone ()Ljava/lang/Object;
    CHECKCAST [Lxx/enums/WidgetProperty;
    ARETURN
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 0
```

Can someone point me to the place where those code is generated? For Java 11.

Comment: Since it's not mentioned in the language spec, there is a high chance that the implementation is compiler-specific. The compiler could also not generate any Java code for `values`, only bytecode.

Comment: Hm... Interesting. Didn't think it could be only bytecode, since I clearly remember for earlier versions of Java there was a Java code. However, my memory could be wrong.

Comment: That code should be relatively easily understood as `return (xx.enums.WidgetProperty[])(xx.enums.WidgetProperty.$VALUES.clone());`.

Comment: wait, are you looking for _java_ code for this generated? no no, it's only byte code, generated by the compiler.